# MySQL update query not working in MySQL command Line and Netbeans

Tags: mysql, database

This is my issue, i write a update command and its says query executed. but still nothing happens?
Can anyone please let me know why this is happening

below is the snapshot

[image]

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an "AND" keyword where you want a comma.

```
... SET col1 = expr  ,  col2 = expr  WHERE ...
                    ^^^
```

But what you've got is

```
... SET col1 = nasty_expression   WHERE ID ...
```

The expression being assigned to developer_id is "`2 AND issue_status = 'Assigned'`"

That expression is being evaluated in a boolean context, and that's evaluating to false, which is a zero, so it's a zero being assigned to the column. Because the column already has a value of 0, no rows are actually being changed.